# "Candy Machine v2" - Solana uploading NFT assets failed - "Transaction was not confirmed in 60.01 seconds". Unknown "Candy Machine PublicKey"

Tags: solana, nft, candy-machine

I've prepared NFT collection of 2 items for uploading it to the Solana blockchain with using "Candy Machine v2" on the mainnet-beta cluster.

According [Solana documentation > Creating the Candy Machine](https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/creating-candy-machine) I've tried to upload assets with the CLI.

I've test it with sending small number of assets (2 items).

Unfortunatelly I've got following error message:

- *"Translating error Error: Transaction was not confirmed in 60.01 seconds. It is unknown if it succeeded or failed. Check signature 2txvVMJ3UK3BHMbppH91uxUL2AS3tNF5Mgf716ZL2kjbgMcffLTMav9d2UFzbeDghH4mcRJNEcZKFq1yATHCtziB using the Solana Explorer or CLI tools."*

Transaction is shown as *"Success - Finalized"* on the solscan:

- https://solscan.io/tx/2txvVMJ3UK3BHMbppH91uxUL2AS3tNF5Mgf716ZL2kjbgMcffLTMav9d2UFzbeDghH4mcRJNEcZKFq1yATHCtziB

**The problem is the funds has stacked.**
How do I get it back?

I have no idea how to retrieve Candy Machine Id.
I guess I could withdraw Rent according to [Withdraw Rent](https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/withdraw) documentation.

When I make next try I'll get the same issue.

My CLI commands is:

```
$ ts-node ~/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload -e mainnet-beta -k ~/.config/solana/mainnet-beta.json -cp ./config.json -c example -rl 1 ./assets

wallet public key: 4SLTKpLxcBLxM6PQwgWveYBeYMDyK6GgvmCPUESBbDL4
(node:4402) ExperimentalWarning: buffer.Blob is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Beginning the upload for 2 (img+json) pairs
started at: 1651274892714
initializing candy machine
Translating error Error: Transaction was not confirmed in 60.01 seconds. It is unknown if it succeeded or failed. Check signature 2txvVMJ3UK3BHMbppH91uxUL2AS3tNF5Mgf716ZL2kjbgMcffLTMav9d2UFzbeDghH4mcRJNEcZKFq1yATHCtziB using the Solana Explorer or CLI tools.
    at Connection.confirmTransaction (/home/adam/metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:2782:13)
    at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (/home/adam/metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/util/send-and-confirm-raw-transaction.ts:33:5)
    at async Provider.send (/home/adam/metaplex/js/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:114:18)
    at async Object.rpc [as initializeCandyMachine] (/home/adam/metaplex/js/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:19:23)
    at async createCandyMachineV2 (/home/adam/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/accounts.ts:156:11)
    at async uploadV2 (/home/adam/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/commands/upload.ts:148:19)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/home/adam/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts:269:7)
Error deploying config to Solana network. Error: Transaction was not confirmed in 60.01 seconds. It is unknown if it succeeded or failed. Check signature 2txvVMJ3UK3BHMbppH91uxUL2AS3tNF5Mgf716ZL2kjbgMcffLTMav9d2UFzbeDghH4mcRJNEcZKFq1yATHCtziB using the Solana Explorer or CLI tools.
    at Connection.confirmTransaction (/home/adam/metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:2782:13)
    at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (/home/adam/metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/util/send-and-confirm-raw-transaction.ts:33:5)
    at async Provider.send (/home/adam/metaplex/js/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:114:18)
    at async Object.rpc [as initializeCandyMachine] (/home/adam/metaplex/js/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:19:23)
    at async createCandyMachineV2 (/home/adam/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/accounts.ts:156:11)
    at async uploadV2 (/home/adam/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/commands/upload.ts:148:19)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/home/adam/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts:269:7)
upload was not successful, please re-run. Error: Transaction was not confirmed in 60.01 seconds. It is unknown if it succeeded or failed. Check signature 2txvVMJ3UK3BHMbppH91uxUL2AS3tNF5Mgf716ZL2kjbgMcffLTMav9d2UFzbeDghH4mcRJNEcZKFq1yATHCtziB using the Solana Explorer or CLI tools.
    at Connection.confirmTransaction (/home/adam/metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:2782:13)
    at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (/home/adam/metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/util/send-and-confirm-raw-transaction.ts:33:5)
    at async Provider.send (/home/adam/metaplex/js/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:114:18)
    at async Object.rpc [as initializeCandyMachine] (/home/adam/metaplex/js/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:19:23)
    at async createCandyMachineV2 (/home/adam/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/accounts.ts:156:11)
    at async uploadV2 (/home/adam/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/commands/upload.ts:148:19)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/home/adam/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts:269:7)
```

My solana config is:

```
$ solana config get
Config File: /home/adam/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com
WebSocket URL: wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/ (computed)
Keypair Path: /home/adam/.config/solana/mainnet-beta.json
Commitment: confirmed
```

Comment: OK, I've found resolution.

Transaction `2txvVMJ3UK3BHMbppH91uxUL2AS3tNF5Mgf716ZL2kjbgMcffLTMav9d2UFzbeDghH4mcRJNEcZKFq1yATHCtziB` has receiver of my "lost" SOL.
It is candy machine address that I used for withdraw rent.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command in your CMD. This command does not require the candy machine ID.

```
ts-node ~/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts withdraw_all \
    -e devnet \
    -k ~/.config/solana/devnet.json
```